# unable to use storing in a haskell script

Tags: haskell

Im new at haskell and Im trying to code the game of Monopoly. Below is the code for moving of the pawns every turn. My problem is I am unable to store the previous sum of the two dices in order to correctly update the current position. However, when i use the storing instruction in he console it works perfectly, yet in the script it says parse error possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets. Also some advice for the concepts of the game would be welcomed. Thanks in advance

```
rollDice1 :: Int
rollDice1 = unsafePerformIO(getStdRandom (randomR (1,6)))
rollDice2 :: Int
rollDice2 = unsafePerformIO(getStdRandom (randomR (1,6)))

move :: Int
move = rollDice1 + rollDice2

let position = move
```

Comment: how are you running it and what is the exact error message? also, is that the full source code?

Comment: note that it's an extremely bad idea to hide non pure random generation behind a pure `Int` type — at the very least it's extremely confusing and can lead to unexpected semantics, or in the worse case invalid runtime behavior. I _strongly_ advise you to keep such logic in the `IO` monad, or use another monad such as the State monad.

Comment: I am running it using a script

Comment: please provide the exact log of how you run it and what the output is.

Comment: the problem is the last line - this will basically only work in GHCi - instead you could just say `position = move` but where is the point? `position` is just another *name* for `move` anyway

Comment: I have tried with IO Int monad, however I cannot acces the Int in order to update the situation of the game during turns

Comment: this will get rather difficult - I think you don't know to much about Haskell and of the way how to work with *pure* languages - have you red something like [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)? I would recommend to do so

Comment: but to help you a bit - instead of *mutating* variables like `position` you should start to think of functions like `moveFigureState :: Figure -> Dice -> GameState -> GameState`

Comment: and do yourself a favor and *forget* for now that a function like `unsafePerformIO` even exists

Comment: Well this was a last resort.. since I seem to be unable to calculate the sum of the two dices to update the position without it. I've found someone's way of extracting the Int of IO monad however it does not seem to work for me

Comment: the usual way is to use *bind* of some form `(>>=)` or the `do` notation like `do value <- dice` - but this will be really hard to explain everything - it would be much easier if you would first read some introduction and then come back and ask specific questions instead

Comment: While you're at it, the word is "dice", not "dices". The singular form of "dice" is "die". "One die, two dice, three dice, etc." The word "dice" can also be a verb, one of whose forms is "dices", but that is definitely not what you meant.

Comment: There is no way of "extracting" an `Int` from `IO Int`. `IO Int` does not contain an `Int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is how you can do something like this without `unsafePerformIO`:

```
module Test where

import System.Random

rollDice :: IO Int
rollDice = randomRIO (1,6)

sumOfTwoDices :: IO Int
sumOfTwoDices = do
    dice1 <- rollDice
    dice2 <- rollDice
    return $ dice1+dice2
```

you should be able to load this into ghci and then play with it:

```
~/Temp $ ghci test.hs 
GHCi, version 7.10.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Test             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Test.
*Test> sumOfTwoDices
3
```

### explanation

You see now all calculations *live inside* IO - so you have to change the return-type accordingly.

`sumOfTwoDices` uses

- the `do` syntax
- then *rolls* the dice and pulls the value out of the `IO Int` value with `dice1 <-` ...
- does this again for `dice2`
- adds the two simple `Int` values with `dice1 + dice2`
- and then wraps them back into `IO` with `return` (it's not what you might know from languages as *C/C++*, *Java* , ...)

the `$` is just me being to lazy to write `return (dice1+dice2)` ;)

Now if you want you can write your complete game inside `IO` (and it would be almost as using any other language) **but** you don't want this - you want to do as much as you can without `IO` and only go back in when you finally need the *random dices*  - but this is just to much to put into a single answer :(

Comment: I ran it using a script and I received this The Type signature for 'sumOftwoDices' lacks an accompanying binding

Comment: I forgot the `$` sorry - inside a `.hs` script with installed `random` package it should load into ghci just fine

Comment: Still the same error, and I have random package installed and included .Sorry to bother you to such lengths, I know I am a dummy.

Comment: can you try to copy&paste all the code as is into a text-editor, save it as `test.hs` and then do the steps I showed below in a terminal (`ghci test.hs` in the same directory you saved your file do, ..)

Comment: It worked now, thanks a lot for your  time and sorry for being such a dummy

Comment: Also can I contact you somehow... I have an example code from someone with the exact same purpose as mine, yet Im having some trouble understanding it, if you are willing I would like to learn more since I am really pressured by time

Comment: you will do fine asking specific questions here - just make sure that you don't let it get to broad - there are a lot of really quick and really smart people around (much smarter than me) and I can not help 24/7 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is fundamentally flawed to begin with. You should read a tutorial on Haskell evaluation semantics. The way you unsafely unwrap IO calls and try to make them look like pure calls is not only dangerous but has already lead you to come to invalid logic. For example the contents your `position` will probably change every time you access it because it's only an alias of `move`, and `move` evaluates to a new random value each time it's accessed.

Alternatively, GHC might instead cache the first value of `move` so even though `position` will then be "stable", you can't generate new moves with `move`.

As to the problem you're having, it's impossible to diagnose without further details as well as you fixing the logic to start with.